# Own Function Template for "Insert"-Method (Vector)

Tags: c++, vector, insert

I am still a beginner with C++. I have the following question: Let's say I have a string with content and I want to copy this content to a vector like this:

```
std::string s{"Professional"};
std::vector<char> v{};
v.insert(s.begin(),s.end());
```

I assume my vector is empty and that I can fill it with the content of the String. For the above i want to have an own Function Template, like:

```
template<typename InputIterator> void insert(InputIterator first, InputIterator last) {

}
```

And here lies the problem. How should I implement this? I would be very happy to have an idea. Thanks

Comment: You need an argument saying *where* the data should be inserted.

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own `charVector`derived from `std::vector<char>` with a method `insert`:

```
struct charVector : std::vector<char>
{
    template<typename InputIterator>
    void insert(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
    {
        assign( first, last );
    }
};

std::string s{"Professional"};
charVector v{};
v.insert( s.begin(), s.end() );
```

If you like a methode which adds data to the end of your `charVector` use `std::copy`and `std::back_inserter`

```
#include <algorithm> // std::copy
#include <iterator>  // std::back_inserter

struct charVector : std::vector<char>
{
    template<typename InputIterator>
    void insert(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
    {
        std::copy( first, last, std::back_inserter( *this ) );
    }
};
```

Comment: He wants to make a template function for abstracting the data type though I think, Although assign can still probably be used here for this?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Acutally I want to integrate the above function method into my already existing class template

    template <typename T> class Test { .....}